# highlight date in mat-calendar doesn't work

Tags: angular

I try to highlight special dates in mat-calendar. this is my code :
app.component.ts:

```
datesToHighlight = ["2019-06-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-06-06T18:30:00.000Z", "2019-06-24T18:30:00.000Z"];
onSelect(event){
  this.selectedDate = event;
  this.datesToHighlight.push('2019-06-27T18:30:00.000Z');
}
dateClass = (d: Date) => {
  const date = d.getDate();
  return (date === 1 || date === 20) ? 'example-custom-date-class' :'';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-calendar>
```

and style.css:

```
.example-custom-date-class {
background: orange;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on angular 13.

css:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell.highlight > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content,
.mat-calendar-body-cell.highlight:hover > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content,
.mat-calendar-body-cell.highlight > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content:hover {
  border-color: #ab4545 !important;
  color: #ab4545 !important;
}
```

ts: (Make sure 'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None' is there in the component)

```
dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
if (view === 'month') {
  return cellDate.toLocaleDateString() ===
    new Date(2022, 5, 1).toLocaleDateString()
    ? ['highlight']
    : [''];
}

return [''];};
```

html:

```
 <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: shuZro, it's the same put the .css in "styles.css" that use ViewEncapsulation.None